# UK visa application same day transit

Tags: visas, uk

I'm currently applying for UK standard tourist visa and have a problem. In the past, I transited non-EEA country (entered and left the country the same day). When I tried to enter that information, the error pops up, because I have entered the same day for entrance and exit dates. I'm confused because I have the stamps in the passport, but can't enter it in the application.

Does any know how to overcome this?

Edit: I'm trying to add transiting through Belarus from 28 May 2018 to 28 May 2018, and the error pops indicating that the ending date must be before the starting date.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What exactly are you trying to enter, and what is the question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have updated the question with a clearer example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when an electronic visa application rejects correct answers for technical reasons, the goal is to **be clear**. Give answers that are as close to the truth as the system will let you, and then enclose an explicit explanation (as a separate sheet, or in an appropriate free-text field) that explains clearly why you've needed to give wrong answers and what the right answer is. That way it won't look like you're trying to deceive or hide anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! For anyone else looking for this, there is a free form text field at the end of the application for additional information about your application.